# how to get Discount range selection for product page at left side bar in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.6, magento-1.9

How to add Discounts in filter at the product page left side bar as like the Price Range? It should be displayed in % format

I'm Having extension for price range,but didn't find any extension for Discounts.

please solute me.. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about layer navigation in categories you need to do the following:

> admin/catalog_product_attribute/index

Create a product attribute called discounts:

> Input type: dropdown 
>   Layered Navigation: Filterable ( with results )
>   Use in Search Results: Yes 
>   Used for Sorting in Product Listing: Yes

Manage Attribute Set for your product:

> admin/catalog_product_set/index

Add the discounts to the section desired.

Set the discount option per product.

Reindex, flush cache.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time. But actually what i need is i want to display that discount as in percentage range in the left side bar. (i.e., need discount range at shopping options block in left side)

Comment: You could instead call the attribute discount & and add a range label on each one yourself. They'll be filterable the same way as a static value.

Comment: yes we can add like that also but what client expecting is once they added special price, it has to calculate its percentage of its own and and need to be displayed in layered navigation filter. please try for that.. it should be in percentage range